# Node js express error hanlding middleware dont recognize 4 elements

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling, server, middleware

I'm trying to create an error-handling middleware, and as you can see in the image attached when I'm making the

```
 app.use((err,req,res,next) => {...})
```

block my IDE is automatically recognized as 3 parameter middleware. and I can't get it to work as err-req-res-next middleware.
I thought - maybe the IDE miss-indexed that block - and tried to run it, and while running the express doesn't recognize an error-handling middleware

[image: 3 parameters identified]

I add the "app.use" in my server.js (which is the same as app.js), and as the last-placed app.use, right before the listen.

I'm using latest express to date: 4.18.1

Any help in finding a solution will be great!

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add these two after all routing methods:

```
// 404 not found error
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send('<h1>error 404 not found</h1>');
})

// 500 server error
app.use((error, req, res, next)=>{
    if(error){
        res.send('500 OOPS :( Something went wrong... Please try again. ')
    }
})
```

Comment: Hello!
Thank for your help, I added the attached code and while the 500 error did catch the error I threw - the middleware was never called (and the IDE still parsing the err as req, etc..)

any more ideas? :)

many thanks

Comment: Can you share the full code with us?

Comment: hey man! thank you very much for your help! unfortunately, the code is not mine to share but your answer led me in the right direction and took me most of the way! much appritiated

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out!

The issue was that I added the "error handling middleware" at the "server.js", it should have been in the placeholder.routes.js of the relevant controller.

[abdurrahim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9080743/abdurrahim-ahmadov) answer really helped in figuring it out, after I added the code he attached I saw it was catching the errors, and the "500 server error" is, technically, an error-handling middleware.

So I added the following code after all the routes **in the routes file**, and managed to handle the different errors I was throwing.

Thanks a bunch!

[image]

Comment: I am glad to hear that I helped you